# how to keep a form activated

Tags: c#, winforms

Now, I have two forms, called form1 and form2, in the form1 there's a button, when I click it, then open the form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ges.produit.Add(p); 
    Form3 f= new Form3(); 
    f.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); 
    foreach (var item in Ges.produit) 
    {
        f.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Qty, item.Prac, item.Prav, item.Disc); 
    }
    this.MdiParent = f.MdiParent; 
    f.Show(); 
    this.Hide(); 
}
```

Question: in the form2, I created a button when I click it, the form2 close and get back to form1 without opening another form1 . How to do?this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding a form and showing another when a button is clicked in a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345666/hiding-a-form-and-showing-another-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-a-windows-forms-ap)

Comment: Post the code you're trying because you just close the form.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ges.produit.Add(p);
            Form3 f= new Form3();
            f.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var item in Ges.produit)
            {
                f.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Qty, item.Prac, item.Prav, item.Disc);
            }
            this.MdiParent = f.MdiParent;
            f.Show();
            this.Hide(); 
        }

Comment: I moved your code to the question where we can actually read it. Feel free to delete your comment. In general, don't be afraid to edit your question to add details that folks have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways, one way is to pass a reference of the parent form to the child form in its constructor, and then when you close the child form call show against this reference.

Another way to accomplish this is when you create the child form inside the parent form, at the same time also wire up the FormClosed event of the child form to re-display the parent form.

The following is an example for both of these methods

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2(this);

        this.Hide();
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void btnShowForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form3 = new Form3();

        form3.FormClosed += (o, args) =>
        {
            this.Show();
        };

        this.Hide();
        form3.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _form1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
        :this()
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.Show();
    }
}
```